# convert date and time to numerical x axis cordinate in cartesian coordinate system

Tags: java, statistics

I need to find linear regression for a particular stock for a period of one year.The data which  i have current is like this

```
DATE        TIME        OPEN    HIGH    LOW     CLOSE   Volume
02-Jan-12   00:00:00    1509.85 1519.9  1471    1495.3  21832
03-Jan-12   00:00:00    1515    1577.9  1481    1565.6  4378
04-Jan-12   00:00:00    1539    1606    1515    1525.8  5485
05-Jan-12   00:00:00    1545    1558.95 1500    1512.35 3639
06-Jan-12   00:00:00    1529.95 1529.95 1486.1  1493.7  1984
07-Jan-12   00:00:00    1507.9  1507.9  1490    1498.05 129
09-Jan-12   00:00:00    1494    1509.95 1453    1480.7  5991
10-Jan-12   00:00:00    1495    1510    1481    1500.05 19725
11-Jan-12   00:00:00    1505    1559.8  1485.1  1499.85 3900
```

For the linear regression my x axis will be the date and time and my y axis would be close price.Is there any way to convert date and time to a numerical format.I tried taking the difference in minutes between two dates but that gives me a wrong slope .Is there any other way in which i can represent date and time in a numerical format for my x axes??

These are the calculations I have done so far to find the slope and intercept for linear regression line .I think the slope is incorrect.

```
            X   Y       XY    sumXY      sumX   sumY       Xsq   sum Xsq    slope
02-Jan-12   0   1495.3  0   1471935316  255970  3088527.45  0   122097690   12.02372705
03-Jan-12   1   1565.6  1565.6                              1       
04-Jan-12   2   1525.8  3051.6                              4       
05-Jan-12   3   1512.35 4537.05                             9       
06-Jan-12   4   1493.7  5974.8                              16      
07-Jan-12   5   1498.05 7490.25                             25      
09-Jan-12   6   1480.7  8884.2                              36      
10-Jan-12   7   1500.05 10500.35                        
11-Jan-12   8   1499.85 11998.8                     
12-Jan-12   9   1522.7  13704.3                     
13-Jan-12   10  1533.2  15332                       
16-Jan-12   11  1535.95 16895.45                        
17-Jan-12   12  1604.15 19249.8                     
18-Jan-12   13  1584.95 20604.35                        
19-Jan-12   14  1570.85 21991.9                     
20-Jan-12   15  1613.15 24197.25
```

Comment: You can just use [unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), it won't affect the regression - when labeling "new point" convert it to unix time as well, and then use your model

Comment: unix time is a ten digit number.i guess it is inconvinient to make calculations using large number

Comment: Inconvenient to who? Aren't you letting your machine do the regression for you? You can easily set the `0` as the earliest time by reducing `x-first` for all values `x` you have to make the range shorter.

Comment: Also, if you are dealing with the data you posted, you can just have x={2,3,4,...,11} that's all the offset you have here.

Comment: Well for this data i am getting the slope and the intercept right by using x ={2,3,4,5..}..Thankyou